# show that for every $h \in E$ such that $\|h\| \leq 1$ we have $|f(h)|\leq \frac{f(a)}{r}.$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a real normed space and f be a non null linear and continuous  on E.
And for every $a \in E \setminus kerf.$ we consider for example
$f(a) >0$  and $\exists r>0$ such that $B(a,r) \subset E \setminus kerf $.
show that for every $h \in E$ such that $\|h\| \leq 1$ we have $|f(h)|\leq \frac{f(a)}{r}.$
I need some hint please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h=\lambda a+u$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $u\in\ker f,$ so that $f(h)=\lambda f(a).$

Assume wlog $\lambda\ne0.$

$$r\le d(a,\ker f)\le\|a+u/\lambda\|=\|h\|/|\lambda|\le1/|\lambda|=|f(a)|/|f(h)|.$$

Comment: Thank you so much but can you explain to me why $r\le d(a,\ker f)$ pls

Comment: It is because (by choice of $r$) $\forall v\in\ker f\quad d(a,v)\ge r.$